# All objects are affected in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Sample:

```
test = {one: 1, two: 'two', three: 3};

arr = [];
arr.unshift(test);
arr.unshift(test);
arr.unshift(test);

arr[0].two = 2;
```

Results:

[image]

What I want? I want change just the value from the `first array`, the others stilling with the value `two` when I access `arr[index].two`. What can I do to solve that?

Comment: you are pushing the same reference in to the array.

Comment: create a new object for eact item in the array.

Comment: @DanielA.White doing something like `arr.unshift(new Object(test))` I have the same result, are you can show me what I need do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are actually adding 3 references to **the same object**. So any modification affects the 3 entries in the array.

What you want is to create **different copies of the object** for each entry, so they are all logically different, and modifiable individually.

You can achieve this by using `Object.assign({}, yourModelObject)`.

For instance, see the following snippet :

```js
let test = {one: 1, two: 'two', three: 3};
let arr = [] 

arr.unshift(Object.assign({}, test));
arr.unshift(Object.assign({}, test));
arr.unshift(Object.assign({}, test));

arr[0].two = 2
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing/unshifting the **same** reference.
Use the `Object.create(...)` to create new reference and then you will be able to modify any single instance within your array

> The `Object.create()` method creates a **new object**, using an existing object to provide the newly created object's `__proto__`

```js
let test = {
  one: 1,
  two: 'two',
  three: 3
};

let arr = [];
arr.push(Object.create(test));
arr.push(Object.create(test));
arr.push(Object.create(test));

arr[0].two = 2;

console.log(arr[0].two)
console.log(arr[1].two)
console.log(arr[2].two)
```

Comment: This creates 3 objects with `test` as the `__proto__`

Comment: if you log out the entire arr with `console.log(arr)` it shows you arrays of object without members, but if you can still access the members of such objects